# Accessing state in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state, setstate

I have a function:

```
    getCommits: function() {
    fetch('/commits').then((response) => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
     })
     .then((commits) => {
       this.setState({commits: commits});
     });
  },
```

I set the state in this function and now I want other functions to access this state. How can I do this?

`this.state.commits` was one idea I had.

```
     getTodaysCommits: function(){
     fetch('/commits').then((response) => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
     })
     .then((commits) => {
       var todaysCommits = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < commits.length; i++) {
         var today = new Date().toDateString();
         var stringToDate = new Date(commits[i].commit.author.date).toDateString();
         if (today == stringToDate){
           todaysCommits.push(commits[i])
         }
       }
       return todaysCommits;
     })
     .then((todaysCommits) => {
       this.setState({commits: todaysCommits});
     })
  },
```

In this function how can I use commits without having to fetch it from api and just use the state set in the previous function?

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.getCommits();}
```

I have my function that gets set on `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your state is set and then you can access it by referring to the context state as `this.state.commits`.

You need to make sure you are referring to the correct context.

Use it in the function as

```
getTodaysCommits: function(){

    var commits = this.state.commits;
    console.log(commits);

}
```

Comment: where would that live in the second function though? and then how do I call a `.then` on it?

Comment: you need not fetch it again just use this state variable.

Comment: ok yeh makes sense, one final question. I have updated to show the whole of my `getTodaysCommits()`. I want to get rid of all the fetch part and replace it with `var commits = this.state.commits;` but that means I cant call my `.then` promise on that?

Comment: whatever you have inside your then call you can access do the same without it. Its not an issue